# Convergence or divergence of a Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial

I have this summation here which says:

[image]

I am asked to find if this sum converged or diverges. The only problem is that I am struggling with the denominator. What is denominator saying? It's just all the odd term being multiplied but I am not really sure how I would represent the denominator explicitly as a function or something.

How would I go about find if this series converges or diverges?

Comment: Note that 

$$3\cdot 5\cdots (2n+3) = \frac{(2n+3)!}{2^{n} (n+1)!}$$

Comment: How did you obtain that?

Comment: Note that 

$$(2n+3)! = \color{red}{2} \cdot   \color{blue}{3} \cdot   \color{red}{4}  \cdots \color{blue}{(2n+1)} \cdot  \color{red}{(2n+2)}  \cdot \color{blue}{(2n+3)} $$

Now  separate the $\color{red}{\text{even}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{odd}}$ terms.

Comment: Okay so I can group the even and odd terms together. There is no division implied anywhere though.

Comment: $$(2n+3)! =( \color{red}{2^{n+1} (n+1)!} )\times\color{blue}{3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3)} $$

Now divide both sides by the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term.

Comment: Ohh wow... Yes okay that makes sense. Thanks. How did you even recognize this type of pattern? Just practice?

Comment: This is related to the double factorial 

$$(2n+1)!! = \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n (n!)}$$

read more here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html and see (6-11) equations. You can then put $n = k+1$ for your case.

Comment: How did you combine $(2n+3)! = \color{red}{2} \cdot   \color{blue}{3} \cdot   \color{red}{4}  \cdots \color{blue}{(2n+1)} \cdot  \color{red}{(2n+2)}  \cdot \color{blue}{(2n+3)}$ into $(2n+3)! =( \color{red}{2^{n+1} (n+1)!} )\times\color{blue}{3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3)}$ ? I don't see how the relationship was formed. The rest of it is fairly obvious of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3) \geq 3\cdot 2^n\cdot n!
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n!}{3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3)} \leq \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n!}{3\cdot 2^n\cdot n!}.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\begin{align}
3\cdot 5 \cdots (2n+3) \geq 3\cdot 2^n\cdot n!
\end{align}$ true?

Comment: It's a hint :).

Comment: Ahaha. Okay let me try to reason it out.

Comment: Another hint: drop the 3s

Comment: No still not seeing it... I tried dividing and stuff but I am not seeing how that's true. Any other hint?

Comment: Actually,  for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $2n+3>2n$. I hope this helps.

Comment: So, $$\overbrace{5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdots (2n+3)}^{n-factors}>\overbrace{2(1)\cdot 2(2)\cdot 2(3)\cdots 2n}^{n-factors}=\overbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdots 2}^{n-factors}\cdot \overbrace{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n}^{n-factors}=2^n\cdot n!$$